# Open eMail from App with predefined text in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, email, url-scheme

Hello i want to open the eMail program from my App and the body should already be defined. I can open the eMail but don't know how to define the body of the eMail as a given Parameter to show a given standard text. Anyone can help? Heres the code i use to open Email:

```
//EMAIL
let email = "foo@bar.com"
let urlEMail = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(email)")

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(urlEMail!) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(urlEMail!)
} else {
print("Ups")
}
```

Comment: Do some research on the `mailto:` URL scheme. You can provide "to" addresses, "cc" addresses, a subject, and the message body. But of course the best option is to do what the answers below suggest.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it using `MFMailComposeViewController`:

```
import MessageUI

let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["email@email.com"])
mailComposerVC.setSubject("Subject")
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Body", isHTML: false)
self.presentViewController(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also, you need to implement `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` from `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` where you should dismiss `MFMailComposeViewController`

Comment: Before you create your mailComposerVC it is not a bad idea to check if you actually can send an email using `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()`

Answer (score 31):

If you'd like to open the built-in email app as opposed to showing the `MFMailComposeViewController` as has been mentioned by others, you could construct a `mailto:` link like this:

```
let subject = "My subject"
let body = "The awesome body of my email."
let encodedParams = "subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
let url = "mailto:foo@bar.com?\(encodedParams)"

if let emailURL = NSURL(url) {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(emailURL) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(emailURL)
    }
}
```

---

Just to save anyone typing, for 2016 the syntax has changed slightly:

```
let subject = "Some subject"
let body = "Plenty of email body."
let coded = "mailto:blah@blah.com?subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

if let emailURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: coded!)
    {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(emailURL)
        {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(emailURL)
        }
```

Comment: the actual correct answer to the question on the page!  thanks man!  :)

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 3 Version**

```
let subject = "Some subject"
let body = "Plenty of email body."
let coded = "mailto:blah@blah.com?subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

if let emailURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: coded!) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(emailURL as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(emailURL as URL)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4.0**

```
    let email = "feedback@company.com"
    let subject = "subject"
    let bodyText = "Please provide information that will help us to serve you better"
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([email])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject(subject)
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(bodyText, isHTML: true)
        self.present(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let coded = "mailto:\(email)?subject=\(subject)&body=\(bodyText)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        if let emailURL = URL(string: coded!)
        {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(emailURL)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.open(emailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (result) in
                    if !result {
                        // show some Toast or error alert
                        //("Your device is not currently configured to send mail.")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `MFMailComposeViewController` like this:

1. Import the MessageUI

   ```
   import MessageUI
   ```
2. Add the delegate to your class:

   ```
   class myClass: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {}
   ```
3. Configure the email preset you want to have

   ```
   let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
   mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
   mail.setSubject("Subject")
   mail.setMessageBody("Body", isHTML: true)
   mail.setToRecipients(["my@email.com"])
   presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
4. Put this method in your code:

   ```
   func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
       dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

There you go, works now.

Answer (score 3):

Updated for Xcode 12.5

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:mailto:someone@example.com")
                                            UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL)
```

or if you would like to add an embedded subject

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body")
```

or if you want to add multiple email addresses

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:mailto:someone@example.com,someoneelse@example.com")
                                                UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to url construction in the other answers, but instead of calling `addingPercentEncoding` you can use `URLComponents`:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "youremail@test.com")
components?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "subject", value: "Your Subject")]

if let mailUrl = components?.url {
    UIApplication.shared.open(mailUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version of @mclaughj answer

```
let email = "foo@bar.com"
let subject = "Your Subject"
let body = "Plenty of email body."
            
let coded = "mailto:\(email)?subject=\(subject)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    
if let emailURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: coded!)
       {
          if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(emailURL as URL){
             UIApplication.shared.open(emailURL as URL)
          }
       }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Apple's way, which you can find in official documentation about [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendingaMailMessage.html). It opens a modal view controller with the email, which is dismissed after sending. Thus user stays in your app.

Comment: OP asked for Swift code, your reference displays Obj-C instead.

Comment: The link leads to Apple's documentation, where are all information, which could Jan possibly need, not only specific parts (methods/properties). Apple has the sample code only in ObjC in this case, but it could be easily translated to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

## 2023

```
extension URL {
    static func generageEmailUrl(email: String, subject: String = "", body: String = "") -> URL {
        if let encodedParams = "subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)"
            .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
            return URL(string: "mailto:\(email)?\(encodedParams)")!
        }
        
        return  URL(string: "mailto:\(email)")!
    }
}
```

usage in SwiftUI from iOS and macOS:

```
Link("Support Email", destination: URL.generageEmailUrl(email: "support@videq.com", subject: "VideQ feedback", body: "some body text") )
```